# How can I skip email validation with Authlogic in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, authlogic

I use Authlogic for authentication in my Rails project.

It provide default validation for email and login field.

But, I want to allow email to be null for join because my service is for mobile and it is difficult to insert email field in mobile device.

How can I skip email validation with Authlogic in Rails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.validate_email_field = false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I was digging for this one for awhile - extending on what jaehyun said - say you want to skip email validation in Authlogic on a conditional basis

```
  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.merge_validates_length_of_email_field_options({:unless => Proc.new { |user| user.has_no_email? }})
    c.merge_validates_format_of_email_field_options({:unless => Proc.new { |user| user.has_no_email? }})
  end
```